AzureAd .NET - React running on same domain
I have a react application and aspcore backend running on the same domain. (everything is redirected to /index.html except /api/
My users need to login Azure AD.
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "{clientId}",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}",
    redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}`,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false
  }
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
root.render(
  <StrictMode><MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <App />
    </MsalProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);

Everytime I call the backend I get the token by:
    // Try to acquire token silently
    const tokenResult = await this.msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
      account: this.account,
      scopes: [{clientId}],
    });

    return tokenResult.accessToken;

Now I need to verify the token in my aspcore backend.
I tried serveral ways of adding Authentication. I had hoped this would be suffient:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

appsettings:
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "{tenantId}",
    "ClientId": "{clientId}",
    "Issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0/",
    "Audience": "{clientId}"
  },

I still get a 401 status code. I've registered one app in the Microsoft Entra Admin Center. Didn't think I had to create two seperate registration because my site runs on the same domain. But I might be wrong. Can someone help me with the correct configuration?

What scope you are using to generate token?

I tried just the clientId as scope and I tried to create a scope: api://{clientId}/read

Have you exposed any APIs and added any custom scopes there? Please include Portal images of added scopes

Think I only need: scopes: ['User.Read'],

User.Read is Microsoft Graph APi scope that cannot be validated and throws 401 error when you verify that token.

You can just use that token to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

@Marcel Hoekstra  "Audience": "api://{clientId}" should be like this.

I created a sample React app frontend and an ASP. NET Core backend with Azure AD integration.

401 status code.

I got above error because of using wrong "Audience":"{ClientID}",so I changed the
"Audience": "api://{ClientId}".
appsettings.json:
 "AzureAd": {
   "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "TenantId": "{TenantId}",
   "ClientId": "{ClientId}",
   "Audience": "api://{ClientId}",
   "Issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0"
 }

Below is my complete program.cs class.
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowReactApp", policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("AllowReactApp");
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

DataController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace serverapi.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(new { message = "Hello from API!" });
        }
    }
}

Below is my complete React Application, I used scope as
scopes: ['api://{ClientId}/access_as_user'] in react app.
App.js:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
function App() {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState('');
  const login = () => {
    instance.loginPopup({
      scopes: ['api://{ClientId}/access_as_user'], 
    });
  };
  const callApi = async () => {
    try {
      const tokenResponse = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        account: accounts[0],
        scopes: ['api://{ClientId}/access_as_user'], 
      });
      const accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
      const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7165/api/Data', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      setApiResponse(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('API call error: ', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React + Azure AD</h1>
      {!accounts.length && <button onClick={login}>Login</button>}
      {accounts.length && <button onClick={callApi}>Call API</button>}
      <pre>{apiResponse && JSON.stringify(apiResponse, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import App from './App';
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: '{Client ID}',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}', 
    redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}`,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  },
};
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <App />
  </MsalProvider>
);

I added the Scope to my app registration as shown below.

Asp. net Output:

React Output:



@Marcel Hoekstra Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
